# Relative project dependencies in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

When specifying Gradle project dependencies, can I avoid using a full absolute project name and use a relative one instead? (i.e. in my example I don't want to explicitly specify :app-a when referencing :domain-a)

```
//Directory structure
app-a/
  domain-a/
    build.gradle
  webapp-a/
    build.gradle
```

WebApp-A build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

//Build.gradle for webapp-a
dependencies {

  // Works
  compile project(':app-a:domain-a')

  //Doesn't work
  compile project(projectDir.path + '/../domain-a/')

  //Doesn't work
  compile findProject('../domain-a')

  //Doesn't work
  compile project(':domain-a')
}
```

Comment: compile project(':' + parent.name + ':domain-a') works but seems hacky

Comment: Here is a working example that works with gradle2.2.1 but not with android studio 1.0.2 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936433/relative-gradle-project-dependency-with-holoeverywhere/27857759#27857759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative names are a bad idea since they make your project depend on the wider project it is located in. That should not be the case. I suggest to avoid using the relative name.

In terms of retrieving the parent project as a dependency this would be done via the default being the parent directory or that failing it would use the usual dependency resolution mechanism, which uses the coordinates (groupId, artifactId and version) and looks the artifact up in the local repository..

Comment: Yep .. I generally strive for relative paths/names ... but this seems like a bad idea in this case (and judging by other gradle build scripts that I've found).

Comment: Whether or not they are a good idea, I don't get why relative paths would be any more project dependent than absolute paths? What do you suggest instead?

Comment: It is better to have the projects be independent and exchange the dependencies/build outputs like any other dependency via a repository manager or at minimum your local repository.

Comment: Good point, then I understand what you mean. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Still, even without the relative paths, this answer does not answer the problem of referring to a parent project as a dependency.

Comment: This does not answer the actual question on how relative paths can be used. I am developing a library where I provide sample projects. The library is developed in a lib\kotlin subfolder while the samples are samples\kotlin. My workspace root is not related to gradle. I simply want to pull lib\kotlin into the samples\kotlin and not spoil my whole library tree with gradle.

Answer (score 44):

For Android development under Android Studio and gradle, here's how to compile a library that isn't under your project's root but has a relative path:

1. Include the library in settings.gradle and override the projectDir:

   ```
   include 'MyTestLibProject:MyTestLib'
   project(':MyTestLibProject:MyTestLib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../MyTestLibProject/MyTestLib')
   ```
2. Edit the build.gradle for the library to use the android-library plugin instead of android, this causes the library outputs to be included into projects that reference it:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'android-library'
   ```
3. Specify that your project has a dependency on the lib by editing the build.gradle for the non-lib project:

   ```
   compile project(path: ':MyTestLibProject:MyTestLib')
   ```
4. If the lib includes any jars that your project also includes, the build will see them as a collision when it is generating the apk. Abstract jars into an additional lib that both the project and lib reference, or just exclude the colliding jar from the main project and let it pick up the jar from the dependency:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: '**/android-support-v4.jar')
       compile project(path: ':MyTestLibProject:MyTestLib')
   }
   ```

DISCLAIMER: This isn't how gradle wants you to do this - you're intended to publish the lib using maven and then reference the dependency using the "POM" of the published lib (which includes the version number). This provides better dependency management - for example, maven simplifies the scenario of having many projects (with varying release cycles) all using various versions of a common lib. The relative path technique described here is a quick way to get up and running for small projects or as an interim step for projects being ported from ant.

Reference: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Creating-a-Library-Project

Comment: Thanks for this, this works! Until all libraries have their maven repo spitting out .aar files, this is the best solution

Comment: Sadly, this does not work for me. Getting those generic "Configuration with name 'default' not found." errors. Sigh.

Comment: @J c What is 'settingsDir' ?. How can i specify absolute path of library project?

Comment: @Hiren Dabhi If I recall, settingsDir would be the directory where settings.gradle is located.

Comment: This is not working from `gradle 2.3.0`. The library module gets added in the android studio. But even after compiling the library module in app build.gradle, the class files are not getting generated for the library.

Comment: How does it answer question? The path in example still has parent project explicitly specified. Am I missing something

Comment: How can I reach a specific module's folder? I want to add a dependency to "app" module, to reach on some aar file on another module's folder. Meaning: `library/build/outputs/aar/library-release.aar`

Answer (score 9):

Although using relative paths might be a bad practice, sometimes you might just need it that way.
Nevertheless, here is how you can get it to work.

You need to create `settings.gradle` file inside webapp-a

webapp-a/settings.gradle

```
include '..:domain-a'
```

Then in webapp-a/build.gradle

```
compile project(':..:domain-a')
```

(haven't tested it myself but it should work)

EDIT:
replaced `../domain-a` by `..:domain-a` in both files

Comment: This stopped working with Gradle 1.11, I don't know why. I had to follow the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

A late answer never hurts. My solution was close to what @lihsus suggested.

Say you have the following project structure:

```
//Directory structure
app-a/
   domain-a/
       build.gradle
   webapp-a/
       build.gradle
```

Make sure your **app-a** has a **build.gradle** and a **settings.gradle**.

In the **settings.gradle** of **app-a** you can then include both modules/projects such as:

```
include ':domain-a'
include ':webapp-a'
```

And then in **webapp-a** you can add **domain-a** as a compile dependency such as you suggested:

```
compile project(':domain-a')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use compile project':'.
Nothing else is required. Now your 'using' project will use this shared project on your file system/Eclipse/IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked a Gradle training and asked about relative paths, I was given the answer that the best practice is the method file("...") handy for relative paths.
You can checkout the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:single_file_paths) .

I have not tested yet, but I would suppose this would work:

`compile findProject(file("domain-a"))`