# The idiomatic structure for gradle project for the tests

Tags: java, gradle, organization

**Task**: what I have is the large *non-Gradle* (make:-)) project, which contains many subprojects, each one in it's own subdirectory. I have to write functional test for some of these subprojects. These subprojects are producing independent results, but with the same structure, so there is many common code for testing these subprojects, so I want to share it in some special location.

**Restrictions**:

- as developers requested, the tests for subprojects should be in the directory of this subproject (to be precise, in the subdirectory, for example, `func_tests`).
- I have some shared dependencies for my test projects, that I usually use, for example, Google Guava, TestNG and so on, and also have some settings for test run (`excludeGroups 'slow'`...) and I prefer this settings to be common, still, that doesn't matter too much.
- symbolic links are accepted way, if that's good design:)
- If it's possible, I want to have IntelliJ IDEA correctly handle this dependency.

**My ideas**:

- symlink `src/main` of every test subproject to some common directory (`src/test` is "individual"). This will greatly support IDE , but it would lead to copying all the dependencies and preferences. Also, I'm very unsure, if that's preferred way in Gradle.
- create common project, which will be [imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744721/relative-project-dependencies-in-gradle) by every subproject, this will save dependencies (will it?), but I'm not sure IDEA will correctly handle this way.

What is the idiomatic way to do this with Gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `samples/java/withIntegrationTests` in your Gradle installation. This will give you some idea how to add your tests (there are other ways too). You want to tweak that setup to make sure that IDEA handles your tests. This is done by customization of `idea.module.scopes`.

Shared code and shared libraries: you can create a map like https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/gradle/dependencies.gradle and use it in different subprojects. BTW: Gradle codebase has a lot of integration tests and you can check how their build is configured to see if you want to apply some ideas.